# Undefined variable issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I am trying to create a excel file from Mysql using php. I found this link:
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=60681
and used his code. However, it generated an error as following:

```
A PHP Error was encountered     

Severity: Notice        

Message: Undefined variable: header     

Filename: controllers/export_database.php       

Line Number: 26
```

My code in controller:

```
public function export ()
    {
$line1="ID\tProduct\tColor\tSales\t";
$line2="1\tPrinter\tGrey\t13\t";
$line3="2\tCD\tBlue\t15\t";
$line4="3\tDVD\tRed\t7\t";
$line5="4\tMonitor\tGreen\t4\t";
$line6="5\tTelephone\tBlack\t2\t";

$data="$line1\n$line2\n$line3\n$line4\n$line5\n$line6\n";

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=extraction.xls"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
print "$header\n$data"; //line 26
   }

}
```

I am not sure why header is an undefined variable. Any thoughts? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header()` function pushes that data to the browser for you. It doesn't create a $header variable, hence the error.

Remove `$header`.